# Sound walls with sound waves

Tags: waves, acoustics, reflection

Is it possible to create such a wall composed with inaudible sound waves that the other sounds are completely reflected when they touch it ? Like a super wall with no transmission through it but with sound waves.
Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first blush, no. One of the most basic properties of waves is that they pass through and interfere with each other instead of colliding. This is why you get resonance, destructive interference, etc. But it means you can't use one wave to reflect another wave.

The mathematical reason for this is that waves are solutions to linear equations describing small excitations of some medium. However, if something extreme happens to the medium, or the excitations become large, the wave equations may become non-linear and waves might be able to interact. For example, a sound wave reflecting off a wall is a solution to the wave equation in the case where the medium changes suddenly (from air to wall). Nonlinearities from large amplitudes lets you do many cool likes, like acoustic levitation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=odJxJRAxdFU

If such a thing were ever possible, my guess is that it would be due to large amplitude sound waves changing the conductive properties of the air in a certain region, making the air there an acoustic wall in nearly exactly the same way a real wall is. However, I doubt you'd be able to do this without other extreme conditions, like high temperature, that would make it act like a barrier for other things besides sound.

Comment: Mmmhhh... This is a pretty good answer. When you say "changing the conductive properties", you think about "air conductivity" ?

Comment: No, I just don't know the right word off the top of my head. The speed of sound in an ideal gas is proportional to $\sqrt{T}$, so if you could change temperature of one region of air drastically you would create a sudden change in the speed of sound, which would look a lot like a boundary between two media.

Comment: So two sound waves with different speed could bounce with each others ?

Comment: Not that I know of. Remember that the speed of a wave is determined by the medium it is in. If it travels from one medium to one with a different wavespeed, refraction and reflection can occur. For example, mirages occur when light waves encounter a large temperature gradient in the air which causes them to bend upwards before they hit the ground. But this is not due to interactions between waves.